# Hydrogen atom laser spectroscopy and Lamb shift

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy, hydrogen, lamb-shift

To sum up I am trying to figure out measuring Lamb shift with precission laser spectroscopy experiment, and I cannot quite put my mind on it. I know that 1S-2S measurement happened through 2PA,Balmer series through saturation spectroscopy and the Lamb shift was measured with differences between energy intervals of 1S-2S and 2S-4S fluorescence. However the autocalibration of the Balmer and Lymann series and the whole dependance remain foggy to me. Could somebody please explain?